# Why does 'u' appear in front of my strings?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I'm newbie to scraping the web.

I've scraped this table with BeautifulSoup in Python but the simbol `u'` appears and it appears neither the table nor its code.

The code is the following :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
first=urllib2.urlopen("http://www.admision.unmsm.edu.pe/res20130914/A/011/0.html").read()
soup=BeautifulSoup(first)
for tr in soup.find_all('tr')[2:]:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text)
```

When I run the code, the result is like this:

```
(u'494560', u'ABAD SAAVEDRA, GERSON HORACIO', u'011', u'1116.8750')
(u'455314', u'ABAD VALVERDE, MARIA ISABEL', u'011', u'1482.7500')
(u'491005', u'ABREGU HUAMAN, MERCEDES LILIANA', u'011', u'503.4000')
(u'457929', u'ACOSTA ABAD, ALEJANDRO FRANCISCO', u'011', u'413.0500')
```

So, my questions are: Why does `u'` appears? and How can I avoid that?

Comment: The u'' is probably your friend.  It means the strings retrieved can have characters from more languages than just English.

Comment: Thanks for the information, the table actually contains characters in Spanish. My first language.

Answer (score 1):

The `u`'s mean that the strings are unicode:

```
>>> v1 = u'a'
>>> v2 = u'b'
>>> type(v1)
<type 'unicode'>
>>> type(v2)
<type 'unicode'>
>>>
```

You can keep them from being printed by removing the parenthesis on the `print` line:

```
print tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text, tds[3].text
```

Below is a demonstration using the variables in the other demonstration:

```
>>> print (v1, v2)
(u'a', u'b')
>>> print v1, v2
a b
>>>
```